# ElectronJS: Select app icon from Alt+Tab selection, what event fires?

Tags: javascript, electron

In my Electron app, I have added menus and appcommands to allow for a lot of things. One being, that you can `CmdOrCtrl+M` to minimize the window. Once the window is minimized, I would like to activate the app by using `Alt+Tab` to select the icon in the Multi-tasking Selector. I assumed that when I select the app icon, that the `app.on('activate', fn)` would fire. But it doesn't. What event fires when you select the app using `Alt+Tab` on OSX?

[image: MultitaskSelector]

Comment: Should probably add that you are using electron; I don't know if it would work, but have you tried focus, rather than activate?

Comment: Are you familiar with that: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Reference/QuartzEventServicesRef/index.html ?

Comment: No. But if I can wrap it in Node, then I can make it work. Do you have an example? @DanielMizerski

Comment: Sadly not, but my friend said that can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a bug—you could listen for the Application `browser-window-focus` event if your app has one or more windows open, but `activate` should definitely fire. I'd file this as a ticket on the Electron project.

Comment: Seems like this event is still not fired. Could you post the link to the ticket you reported?